# Solving leetcode #46 Permutations

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to solve `leetcode #46` [Permutations](https://leetcode.com/problems/permutations/). The question is:

> Given an array nums of distinct integers, return all the possible permutations. You can return the answer in any order:
>
> ```
> Input: nums = [1,2,3]
> Output: [[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]
> ```

Here is a solution in JavaScript to the problem:

```js
let permute = function(nums) {
    if(nums.length === 0) return [nums];
    let res = [], len = nums.length,used = new Array(len).fill(false);

    let backtrack = function(currPermutation){
        if(currPermutation.length === nums.length){
            res.push([...currPermutation]);
            return;
        }

        for(let i = 0; i < len; ++i){
            if(used[i]) continue;

            currPermutation.push(nums[i]);
            console.log("curr perm = ",currPermutation);
            used[i] = true;
            backtrack(currPermutation);
            currPermutation.pop();
            used[i] = false;
        }
    }

    backtrack([]);
    return res;
};

permute([1,2,3]);
```

For the input `nums = [1,2,3]` here is the result of the `console.log("curr perm = ",currPermutation`:

```
curr perm =  [ 1 ]
curr perm =  [ 1, 2 ]
curr perm =  [ 1, 2, 3 ]
curr perm =  [ 1, 3 ]
curr perm =  [ 1, 3, 2 ]
curr perm =  [ 2 ]
curr perm =  [ 2, 1 ]
curr perm =  [ 2, 1, 3 ]
curr perm =  [ 2, 3 ]
curr perm =  [ 2, 3, 1 ]
curr perm =  [ 3 ]
curr perm =  [ 3, 1 ]
curr perm =  [ 3, 1, 2 ]
curr perm =  [ 3, 2 ]
curr perm =  [ 3, 2, 1 ]
```

What I don't understand is when `curr perm = [1,2,3]` why does it pop the number 2 instead of number 3, same thing when `curr perm = [2,1,3]` why does it pop 1 instead of 3 and obviously same thing when `curr perm = [3,1,2]` why does it pop 1 instead of 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when `curr perm = [1,2,3]` why does it pop the number 2 instead of number 3?

It *does* pop the number 3: there are two consecutive `pop()` calls happening (as recursion unwinds) and one `push` (where you have your `console.log`).

All this will become clearer if you also log the `pop` actions, and add some indentation to reflect how deep we are in the recursion tree:

```js
let permute = function(nums) {
    if(nums.length === 0) return [nums];
    let res = [], len = nums.length,used = new Array(len).fill(false);

    let backtrack = function(currPermutation, indent="") {
        if(currPermutation.length === nums.length){
            console.log(`${indent}found permutation: ${currPermutation}`);
            res.push([...currPermutation]);
            return;
        }

        for(let i = 0; i < len; ++i){
            if(used[i]) continue;

            currPermutation.push(nums[i]);
            console.log(`${indent}pushed ${nums[i]} to permutation: ${currPermutation}`);
            used[i] = true;
            backtrack(currPermutation, indent + "  ");
            currPermutation.pop();
            console.log(`${indent}popped ${nums[i]} from permutation: ${currPermutation}`);
            used[i] = false;
        }
    }

    backtrack([]);
    return res;
};

permute([1,2,3]);
```

Comment: now I got confused by another thing... if it did indeed pop 3 then 2 then it must have also set used[i] = false for the number 3 then the number 2, if so then when pushing again why did it skip the number 2 and pushed the number 3?

Comment: Because the loop variable moved to the next index.

Answer (score 0):

The popping of the numbers happens in reverse order because the code explores the possibilities in a depth-first manner. It means that it first goes as deep as possible in one direction before backtracking and exploring other options.

So, when `currPermutation` is `[1,2,3]`, the code pops the number 2 first because it has already explored all the possibilities with 1 as the first element and 2 as the second element. It needs to backtrack to try other options, which is why 2 is popped before exploring other numbers.

Similarly, for `[2,1,3]`, the code pops 1 before exploring other numbers because it has already explored all the possibilities with 2 as the first element and 1 as the second element.